# Assignment Condition in Python While Loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

In C, one can do

```
while( (i=a) != b ) { }
```

but in Python, it appears, one cannot.

```
while (i = sys.stdin.read(1)) != "\n":
```

generates

```
    while (i = sys.stdin.read(1)) != "\n":
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(the  `^` should be on the `=`)

Is there a workaround?

Comment: oh that's awkward... how does `readline()` compare to `raw_input()`?

Comment: @tekknolagi He probably didn't received your comment. It's a good idea to ping a person by adding `@name` to the comment text.

Comment: @JochenRitzel see my comment? sorry :)

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work in Python is that assignments are *statements* and not *expressions* -- it's simply due to the grammar production rules.

Comment: `sys.stdin.readline()` reads a line from `stdin` and `raw_input` reads a line from the console.

Comment: @JochenRitzel how do those differ?

Comment: See the Python FAQ for an explanation: [Why can’t I use an assignment in an expression?](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression). It advocates iterators or `while True` instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use break:

```
while True:
    i = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if i == "\n":
       break
    # etc...
```

Comment: @FalconMomot This seems like a perfectly reasonable pattern to me. What does it matter where the loop is broken? Either the terminating condition will happen, or it won't. If `i == "\n"` doesn't happen inside the loop (causing a break), it wouldn't have happened in the while-loop's condition argument either.

Answer (score 42):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), it's now possible to capture an expression value (here `sys.stdin.read(1)`) as a variable in order to use it within the body of `while`:

```
while (i := sys.stdin.read(1)) != '\n':
  do_smthg(i)
```

This:

- Assigns `sys.stdin.read(1)` to a variable `i`
- Compares `i` to `\n`
- If the condition is validated, enters the `while` body in which `i` can be used

Comment: Yes, and thank you!  Best answer here.

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish this using the built-in function [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) using the two-argument call method:

```
import functools
for i in iter(fuctools.partial(sys.stdin.read, 1), '\n'):
    ...
```

Documentation for this:

> [`iter(o[, sentinel])`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter)
>   ...
>   If the second argument, *sentinel*, is given, then *o* must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call *o* with no arguments for each call to its [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) method; if the value returned is equal to *sentinel*, [`StopIteration`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.
>
> One useful application of the second form of [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) is to read lines of a file until a certain line is reached. The following example reads a file until the `readline()` method returns an empty string:

```
with open('mydata.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
        process_line(line)
```

Answer (score 8):

A version without `functools`:

```
for i in iter(lambda: sys.stdin.read(1), '\n'):
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I like imm's and Marks answers using `break`, but you could also do:

```
a = None
def set_a(x):
    global a
    a = x
    return a

while set_a(sys.stdin.read(1)) != '\n':
    print('yo')
```

though I wouldn't recommend it.