# Python equivalent to C-like assignment in conditional

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assignment Condition in Python While Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780998/assignment-condition-in-python-while-loop)

What's the equivalent of this:

```
while (line = p.stdout.readline()) != '':
    ...
```

in Python?

I don't like having to do this:

```
line = p.stdout.readline()
while line != '':
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    line = p.stdout.readline()
```

Although I've been using the latter for years... I suspect there is no alternative. I thought `p.stdout` supported iteration, like

```
for line in p.stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

but unfortunately it doesn't, unlike the handle returned from `open()` for example.

**Edit:** Sorry, I was wrong, it does support it, the problem is that I can't get it out right away like I can with `p.stdout.readline()`. Adding `sys.stdout.flush()` doesn't seem to help, so it must be getting buffered inside `p.stdout`.

Comment: `for line in p.stdout:` doesn't make much sense.  It's *output*.  Why do you think you can read it?

Comment: duplicates: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780998/assignment-condition-in-python-while-loop), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161578/variable-assignment-in-expressions) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631128/assignment-in-while-loop-in-python) ... I just search python+assignment+while

Comment: S.Lott: it's the stdout from another process.

Comment: julio: thanks, but only one of those dupes was helpful and the answer I was looking for was down at the bottom with 0 votes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the built-in function [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) using the two-argument call method:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    ...
```

Documentation for this:

> [`iter(o[, sentinel])`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter)
>   ...
>   If the second argument, *sentinel*, is given, then *o* must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call *o* with no arguments for each call to its [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) method; if the value returned is equal to *sentinel*, [`StopIteration`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.
>
> One useful application of the second form of [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) is to read lines of a file until a certain line is reached. The following example reads a file until the `readline()` method returns an empty string:

```
with open('mydata.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
        process_line(line)
```

**edit:** Based on your edit it looks like your actual problem is related to buffering.  Based on the context I am guessing you are using `subprocess.Popen()` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.  Instead of using the file handle `p.stdout` directly you should be [`p.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to read the output of your subprocess.

Comment: You're right. I'm using subprocess.Popen() with stdout=subprocess.PIPE. I've tried using p.communicate() but then I don't get the stdout from the process in real-time, I get it after the process has died. I've been told that pexpect is what I really should use, but I don't want to...I should be able to use subprocess, and it seems to work fine if I use readline(), which is what I've used in the past.